# Monitoring Rebus Queues

Tags: sql-server, monitoring, message-queue, rebus

I have an application using Rebus with SQL Server as a transport layer (yes, I know this is not the ideal transport layer) and I'm, trying to find an out-of-the-box tool to do real-time monitoring of the queues. I tried Rebus Snoop but I found that it is not compatible with SQL Server.

Does anyone know a way to monitor Rebus queues?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Rebus queues" is not really a thing, so you most likely want to turn to whatever broker you are using and use some kind of monitoring tool for that.

E.g. if you're using Azure Service Bus, you can use the Azure Portal's built-in metrics to figure out queue lengths, request rates, etc.

But since it looks you're using SQL Server as the transport, there doesn't really (to my knowledge) exist any kind of compatible "queue monitoring tool" - you'd probably find loads of tools (e.g. from RedGate) that can help with looking at your SQL Server's performance metrics, but it doesn't know that you happen to be using your SQL Server as a message broker.

You can of course also turn to [Rebus Pro](https://pro.rebus.fm/) that comes with Fleet Manager, which can help with some of the things. It's a commercial product though, so it might not be the answer you were hoping for.

Comment: I'm already in contact with you :-)